# How to force delete files from Trash on Silicon based Macs

Tags: time-machine, bootcamp, migration, trash

This is a follow up question to by previous posting: [Why is Bootcamp Assistant on my MacBook Pro (M2) after using Migration Assistant?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/462416/why-is-bootcamp-assistant-on-my-macbook-pro-m2-after-using-migration-assistant)

---

For some reason while running the various delete methods in my previous posting, I now have "Bootcamp Assistant.app" files in my trash that I am unable to delete.  I keep getting an error that the files (in the trash) cannot be deleted as they are used by MacOS.

I have googled around and tried every possible solution, but no luck. Is my only option to do a Time Machine restore? Seems rather drastic for such a simply problem.

Help!

Comment: You can't delete *anything* the Mac considers part of the system. The volume is signed & sealed. [There must be an existing QA on this here somehwre… searching…] See https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secd698747c9/web

Comment: Ah, I see it was already incorporated into Andy Griffiths' answer on the linked QA. See if it will let you put it back on right click. Put Back tends to only work if the Finder did the deletion; trying to hammer it with Terminal may be more… terminal.]

Comment: Oh darn it.  Guess I have to use a Time Machine restore.  That always makes me nervous. Like a nuclear option.

Comment: You could just try a reinstall. It should put the system back as it was without touching user data.